# How can I use a string name as a function call? If string = 'sum' and function is sum(a, b)?

Tags: javascript, string, function

That's about it. I have a string = "sum" and a function named sum(a,b), how can I substitute my string to call that function;

```
string = "sum"
function sum(a,b)
```

So basically to call that function, I would want to execute it like

```
string(a, b)
```

Comment: Geez got downvoted for asking an existing question. Thanks for the help tho and pointing me to the right direction, still appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use dictionary, where you define all existing functions:

```js
const funcs = {
    sum: function(a, b) {

    },
    someStuff: function(r, f) {

    }
};
//call it:
funcs["sum"](a, b);
```

You can simply access your function via indexing with the strings

Comment: This worked, I also just found that window[funcName](a, b) is the best solution for this. Thanks for your answer! Definitely something I can use in the future.

Comment: oh yeah, this solution is "universal", as it works also in Node.js or backend wise but in a browser you can use the window object, sure

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted your answer btw, just won't reflect cause of reputation. I appreciate the shared knowledge good sir.